# How to disable HTML tag validation on a specific TextBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, textbox, asp.net-4.0

I have a form where one of the fields would allow entry of HTML tags.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="someID" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" />
```

In this field I have a `RequiredFieldValidator` validation only. Unfortunately, after any PostBack if the content of any of the fields includes HTML tags or any other potentially dangerous code - the entire ViewState is cleaned.

Setting `ValidateRequest` to `false` does not help.

I'm using IIS 7.5 and .NET 4.0.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would like to get the content of textbox including HTML tags after postback. If I enter clear text to it, everything works. But if in the middle will be even <b> ViewState is crashing and I get nothing.

Comment: This sounds like Request Validation. What happens if you set ValidateRequest=false - its same error or different.

Comment: As I wrote, setting ValidateRequest to false does not help, which is very strange behavior. Now I try to encode the HTML on the client side just before sending the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to set the

```
 <system.web>
       <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
 </system.web>
```

in addition to : `<%@ Page ValidateRequest="false">` on top of the page.

If you want to disable request validation for whole application, set :

```
<system.web>
      <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Is there any way to handle the input before request validation 4.0 does it? As I read it is validated before the BeginRequest phase of an HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a jqueryvalidator instead, and then validate on post as well.. It gives you more control and can give you some "smoother" effects.

For example:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator

Comment: But how your solution is solving my problem of losing ViewState, when I try to send html tags in a textbox?