# Validate Request in .net 4.0 returning 500 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have an application in .net 4.0 that I need to turn Validate Request off for. 
I have put *ValidateRequest = false* in the .aspx page but that does nothing. I then added

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode = "2.0"/>
```

in the web.config file inside *system.web* section but the application now returns *500 - Internal server error*.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: what are you expecting ?

Comment: I have a WYSWIYG field where I need to be able to enter HTML. But this throws the Validate Request error.

Comment: you mean on entering HTML tags in textbox it give error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 500 error was because of an already existing httpRuntime tag in the web.config file, hence the new one was resulting in a duplicate tag! So I now added requestValidationMode="2.0" to the existing httpRuntime tag, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set the

```
<system.web>
       <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
</system.web>
```

in addition to : `<%@ Page ValidateRequest="false">` on top of the page.

If you want to disable request validation for whole application

```
<system.web>
      <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

Here is more [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656523/how-to-disable-html-tag-validation-on-a-specific-textbox)

Comment: <pages validateRequest="false" /> is returning a 500 error as well!

Comment: Figured! The 500 error was because of an already existing httpRuntime tag in the web.config file, hence the new one was resulting in a duplicate tag! So I now added *requestValidationMode="2.0"* to the existing httpRuntime tag, and it works perfectly! Thanks you for trying to help.